# Can't get my led bulb to turn on using triac and optocoupler

Tags: triac, optoelectronics

I have made the below circuit but my LED bulb won't turn on, although circuit works fine if replace the led bulb with a small led and ac supply with 5v dc supply.
Can someone guide me in a right direction?
Sorry I forgot to add the resistor in the diagram but I am using a resistor between 5v and led input, also the ic is MOC3020 Optocoupler and triac is BT136

Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: If the 6-pin device is something like an MOC3041, you will have destroyed the LED and possibly compromised the safety isolation by putting 5V directly on the LED. Not sure you should be messing with the mains at this point- a lethal shock is possible.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the resistor in the diagram but I am using a resistor between 5v and led input, also the ic is MOC3020 Optocoupler and triac is BT136

Comment: @HarshGupta please draw the full exact schematic of what you're considering, and label it appropriately. We have a schematic editor built into the question editor!

Comment: Are you sure your LED bulb is enough of a load to turn on your triac? Can you check the voltage across the MT1 and MT2 terminal safely?

Comment: "TRIACs may also fail to turn on reliably with reactive loads if the current phase shift causes the main circuit current to be below the holding current at trigger time. To overcome the problem DC may be used or a pulse trains to repeatedly trigger the TRIAC until it turns on." -wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRIAC

Comment: Does your circuit work if you replace the LED bulb with a 50-100W incandescent?

Comment: Update I followed the circuit showed in  the following video and it works, still confused what was wrong  https://youtu.be/svYsNfAOtyw

Comment: Sorry, but we're not going to watch a video to try to understand what you are doing. Take a screengrab. Note that your opto symbol in your schematic sketch doesn't show the inner LED and transistor symbols so it is impossible to determine if you have connected it correctly without having to read the datasheets. You already know that you have a problem with the missing resistor in the schematic so you should fix it.